# Storing a Passphrase for SQL Server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, security

We have a web application that contains sensitive data.  Currently we are using sql server 2008 and using DECRYPTBYPASSPHRASE and ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE for the sensitive columns.

The key was exposed and now they want to change the key.

The most important thing is what is the best practices for storing the pass phrase.  The application is a asp.net connecting to a sql server 2008.  The sql admins do not want it stored anywhere in the database.  But then it will stored in the application server and will be transmitted over the wire.

Secondly,  I don't like the fact that I have to decrypt then re-encrypt to change the key.  Is there a better was of encrypting the sensitive data.

thanks in advance.

Comment: We need more information to make recommendations of best practices. What data are you encrypting? Who should have access? etc.

Comment: It is personal information. The information should only be viewed who has access to the application.  They dont even want the SQL Admins to be able to see the data